# Update columns ONLY with properties from JSON

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

How i can update only fields with non-null value?

I have a class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons",
    schema = "persons_info")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "first_name",
        nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name",
        nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty("last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer age;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id",
        referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Address address;

    // setters and getters
}
```

My buisness logic: i want update some fields of class in table, and need ignore null values of mapped from JSON (example: i need update ONLY columns first_name, last_name, and city (in Address)):

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "first_name" : "John",
  "last_name" : "Smith",
  "address" : {
    "city" : "New-York"
  }
}
```

But when i tried send JSON i took exception:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : ru.jankbyte.autopolice.entity.Address.flat
```

I tried to remove `nulable = false` from columns and setting `@DynamicUpdate` annotation under classes but thats didnt work

My rest controller and service methods:

```
//controller
@PostMapping(value = {"/{id}"},
    consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
    produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public Person update(@PathVariable("id") Long id,
@RequestBody Person person) {
    return service.update(id, person);
}

// service
public Person update(Long id, Person person) {
  person.setId(id);
  return save(person);
}
```

Comment: You might find some ideas on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-json-patch